# Drupal Commerce: Can I have product list and checkout in the same page?

Tags: commerce

I have a D7 site and I´m trying to implement Drupal Commerce.

I just need a page where the user can select the product from a list, and give some information about himself (billing information). And at the bottom it should be the "buy" button.

I don´t want a cart, the possibility of "continue shopping" and stuff like that.

How may I do that with Drupal Commerce? I´ve watched all day the videos and read some documentation, but it really seems over complicated when you just want a simple thing (opposed to a big ecommerce site).

Any guidance, tip or help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Commerce Express Checkout](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_express_checkout)

> The Express Checkout button redirects to the Checkout page directly,
>   without going to the Cart first, It also removes the Review page and
>   adds the Payment checkout pane to the Checkout page, so the whole
>   checkout process is done on one page.

[image]

Ckeck

1. http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/952/all-checkout-steps-one-page
2. http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/express-checkout-drupal-commerce